# OAuth2.0 token post request is responding 401 (invalid_client)

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, axios, google-oauth, http-status-code-401

I am very new to the Google OAUth2.0 authentication and thus my question sounds like dumb. However, I am stuck with this problem quite a time and need your input to solve it.

I was integrating the Globus login within [my app](https://p2irc-data-dev.usask.ca/welcome). Globus login using Google OAuth-2 protocol for authentication. According to the [Globus Auth developer guide](https://docs.globus.org/api/auth/developer-guide/#obtaining-authorization), I successfully redirect the app to their authorization service, the user can put their credential to authenticate, and the app receives the code returned from the Globus Auth server upon successful authentication. Next step is sending the code to the Token endpoint to get the access token. I used the following code:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');    
export const logInGlobus = (payload) => {
let tokenUri = encodeURIComponent(payload.redirect_uri);
let client_id = 'out app client id'
let client_secret = 'client secret generated for authentication'
let cred = btoa(client_secret);

return axios.post('https://auth.globus.org/v2/oauth2/token',
querystring.stringify({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: payload.code,
    redirect_uri: tokenUri,
    client_id: client_id
}),
{
    headers:{
        Authorization: 'Basic '+ cred,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
})
 .then(response => {
     return{
         res: response,
         success: true
     }
 })
 .catch(err => {
     return{
         res: err,
         success: false
     }
 })
```

}

I am getting 401 {"error":"invalid_client"} code for this post request from the server. What am I missing?

N.B: I have tried without client secret, client id, not encoding redirect URL. No luck so far>

I would really appreciate your effort if you show me some light. Thanks for your time.

====Edited====

The error from the console at the browser is attached

[image]

Comment: can you attach screenshots of the exact error

Comment: The error from the console is attached. YOu can reproduce the error by clicking the Login button at the top of the window of my application at p2irc-data-dev.usask.ca and then clicking Globus login and performing the authentication at Globus.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had to put the client secret at the body of the post request. The following code resolves my problem.

```
var querystring = require('querystring');

export const logInGlobus = (payload) => {
let client_id = 'app client id'
let client_secret = 'client secret generated for authentication'

return axios.post('https://auth.globus.org/v2/oauth2/token',
querystring.stringify({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: payload.code,
    redirect_uri: payload.redirect_uri,
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret
}),
{
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
})
 .then(response => {
     return{
         res: response,
         success: true
     }
 })
 .catch(err => {
     return{
         res: err,
         success: false
     }
 })
```

}